# MARS MIPS Out of Range Error

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I'm a newbie at MIPS and am attempting a program to find the value of the max number in a pseudo random array. However, I get an out of range error on a line I was fairly sure was allocated proper memory and such. Most of the skeleton code, comments, etc were given, I just am attempting to write the find_max function. I commented at the line giving me issues.

```
    .data               #data segment
nl:     .asciiz "\n"        #ASCII for a new line
separator:  .asciiz ":"     #string that seprates index from number 

msg1:   .asciiz "The function returned "

msg2:   .asciiz "\nThe maximum value is "
li $v0, $t5
#.asciiz 
msg3:   .asciiz "\nThe address of the word is "
#.asciiz 
li $v0, $t6

.align 2        # important for words
buffer: .space 4096     # allocate space for 1K words

.text           # Code segment
.globl  main        # declare main to be global

main: 
addi    $sp, $sp, -4    # allocate space on the stack for $s0
sw  $s0, ($sp)  # save $s0

li  $s0, 16     # specify the size of the array, must be less than 1024

la  $a0,name    # load the address of "name" into $a0
li  $v0,4       # system call, type 4, print an string, *$a0
syscall         # call the "OS"

# call 
la  $a0, buffer 
move    $a1, $s0    
jal init_array  # initialize the array with random values

la  $a0, buffer
move    $a1, $s0
jal print_array     # call print. You can comment it out.

# call your find_max function

la  $a0, buffer
move    $a1, $s0
lw  $t0, 0($a0)
la  $t5, 0($a0)
jal find_max    # call find_max
lw  $v0, 0($t0)
lw  $v1, 0($t5)
# add code to print the results
# print the returned value
la  $a0, msg1   # print mssage 1
li  $v0, 4
syscall

# print the maximum value
la  $a0, msg2   # print mssage 2
li  $v0, 4
syscall

# print the address of the value (in hex).
la  $a0, msg3   # print mssage 3
li  $v0, 4
syscall

la  $a0, nl     # print end of line

syscall

# restore  $s0. You can check $sp here to make sure the stack is maintained     correctly. 
lw  $s0, ($sp)  # load $s0
addi    $sp, $sp, 4 # restore $sp
Exit:   lw  $v0, 0($t5)
lw  $v1, 0($t6)
#li $v0,10      # System call, type 10, standard exit
syscall         # ...and call the OS

find_max: # your implementation of find_max
addi    $sp, $sp, -16   # allocate space on the stack for four registers
sw  $s0, ($sp)  # save $s0
sw  $s1, 4($sp) # save $s1
sw  $s2, 8($sp) # save $s2
sw  $s3, 12($sp)    # save $s3
# put your code below. 
# You can use temporary registers and $s0 to $s3
add $t1,$t1,1 # increment index i by 1

beq $t1,$s0,Exit # if all elements examined, quit

sll $t2,$t2,2 # compute 4i in $t2

add $t2,$t2,$s1 # form address of A[i] in $t2
# THIS IS THE LINE GIVING PROBLEMS
lw $t3,0($t2) # load value of A[i] into $t3

slt $t4,$t0,$t3 # maximum &lt; A[i]?

beq $t4,$zero,find_max # if not, repeat with no change

addi $t0,$t3,0 # if so, A[i] is the new maximum

addi $t5, $t2, 0
# restore saved registers. 
# make sure $sp is restored if you changed it.
lw  $s0, ($sp)  
lw  $s1, 4($sp)  
lw  $s2, 8($sp)  
lw  $s3, 12($sp)     
addi    $sp, $sp, 16    # restore $sp
    jr  $ra                 # return to calling routine
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the function you had to write was using the wrong register when calculating the array index:

Change:

```
sll $t2,$t2,2 # compute 4i in $t2
```

Into:

```
sll $t2,$t1,2 # compute 4i in $t2
```

But, your function also had a much more *severe* bug. You were looping back to the function beginning and creating *multiple* stack frames in the process. I think you may have realized this on some level which is why you tried to compensate and exit the function with a jump to `Exit:` [which is part of `main`].

Your calculation function would also terminate prematurely after finding the first maximum. It would *not* continue to loop through the remainder of the array to find better (i.e. larger) values.

There were a number of other bugs as well.

I've created two versions of your program. One with annotations regarding the bugs. And, a second version, cleaned up, and working.

---

Here is the annotated version [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
    .data                           # data segment
nl:         .asciiz     "\n"        # ASCII for a new line
separator:  .asciiz     ":"         # string that seprates index from number

msg1:       .asciiz     "The function returned "

# NOTE/BUG: these "li" are misplaced and have no meaning
msg2:       .asciiz     "\nThe maximum value is "
    ###li       $v0,$t5
msg3:       .asciiz     "\nThe address of the word is "
    # .asciiz
    # .asciiz
    ###li       $v0,$t6

    .align  2                       # important for words
###buffer:      .space      4096        # allocate space for 1K words
buffer:     .space      128     # allocate space for 1K words
bufe:

    .text                           # Code segment
    .globl  main                    # declare main to be global

main:
    addi    $sp,$sp,-4              # allocate space on the stack for $s0
    sw      $s0,($sp)               # save $s0

    # specify the size of the array, must be less than 1024
    la      $s1,bufe                # get address of array end
    la      $a0,buffer              # get address of array
    subu    $s1,$s1,$a0             # get byte length of array
    srl     $s0,$s1,2               # get word count of array

    # NOTE/BUG: "name" is undefined
    ###la       $a0,name                # load the address of "name" into $a0
    ###li       $v0,4                   # system call, type 4, print an string, *$a0
    ###syscall                          # call the "OS"

    # call
    la      $a0,buffer
    move    $a1,$s0
    jal     init_array              # initialize the array with random values

    la      $a0,buffer
    move    $a1,$s0
    jal     print_array             # call print. You can comment it out.

    # call your find_max function

    la      $a0,buffer
    move    $a1,$s0

    # NOTE/BUG: these serve no purpose
    lw      $t0,0($a0)
    la      $t5,0($a0)

    jal     find_max                # call find_max

    # NOTE/BUG: these serve no purpose
    lw      $v0,0($t0)
    lw      $v1,0($t5)

    # NOTE/BUG: the messages are printed below, but not the actual values

    # add code to print the results
    # print the returned value
    la      $a0,msg1                # print mssage 1
    li      $v0,4
    syscall

    # print the maximum value
    la      $a0,msg2                # print mssage 2
    li      $v0,4
    syscall

    # print the address of the value (in hex).
    la      $a0,msg3                # print mssage 3
    li      $v0,4
    syscall

    la      $a0,nl                  # print end of line

    syscall

    # restore  $s0. You can check $sp here to make sure the stack is maintained     correctly.
    lw      $s0,($sp)               # load $s0
    addi    $sp,$sp,4               # restore $sp

Exit:
    # NOTE/BUG: these serve no purpose
    lw      $v0,0($t5)
    lw      $v1,0($t6)

    # NOTE/BUG: the "li" should _not_ be commented out
    # li $v0,10      # System call, type 10, standard exit
    syscall                         # ...and call the OS

# your implementation of find_max
#
# arguments:
#   a0 -- buffer address
#   a1 -- buffer count
#
# registers:
#
find_max:
    addi    $sp,$sp,-16             # allocate stack space for four registers
    sw      $s0,($sp)               # save $s0
    sw      $s1,4($sp)              # save $s1
    sw      $s2,8($sp)              # save $s2
    sw      $s3,12($sp)             # save $s3

    # NOTE/BUG: the "max" value is never initialized to anything

    # put your code below.
    # You can use temporary registers and $s0 to $s3

    # NOTE/BUG: $t1 has _not_ been initialized
    add     $t1,$t1,1               # increment index i by 1

    # NOTE/BUG: we just want to exit the function and _not_ the program -- this
    # bug is linked to the one below
    beq     $t1,$s0,Exit            # if all elements examined, quit

    # NOTE/BUG: this should be:
    #   sll $t2,$t1,2
    ###sll      $t2,$t2,2               # compute 4i in $t2
    sll     $t2,$t1,2               # compute 4i in $t2

    add     $t2,$t2,$s1             # form address of A[i] in $t2
    # THIS IS THE LINE GIVING PROBLEMS
    # NOTE/FIX: with the bugfix it won't
    lw      $t3,0($t2)              # load value of A[i] into $t3

    slt     $t4,$t0,$t3             # maximum &lt; A[i]?

    # NOTE/BUG: this should _not_ loop back to find_max as that will create
    # _multiple_ stack frames -- it is because of _this_ bug that you
    # tried to compensate and leave this function by jumping to Exit
    beq     $t4,$zero,find_max      # if not, repeat with no change

    # NOTE/BUG: if you set a new maximum, you still have to loop back and _not_
    # just exit this function. you may have found the _first_ maximum but there
    # could be others (i.e. larger values)
    addi    $t0,$t3,0               # if so, A[i] is the new maximum

    addi    $t5,$t2,0

    # restore saved registers.
    # make sure $sp is restored if you changed it.
    lw      $s0,($sp)
    lw      $s1,4($sp)
    lw      $s2,8($sp)
    lw      $s3,12($sp)
    addi    $sp,$sp,16              # restore $sp
    jr      $ra                     # return to calling routine

# init_array -- initialize array with random values
#
# arguments:
#   a0 -- array address
#   a1 -- array count
#
# registers:
#   t0 -- array address
#   t1 -- array count
init_array:
    move    $t0,$a0                 # prevent value from being clobbered
    move    $t1,$a1                 # prevent value from being clobbered

init_loop:
    li      $v0,41                  # syscall for random int
    li      $a0,0                   # specify which generator to use
    syscall

    sw      $a0,0($t0)              # store into array
    addiu   $t0,$t0,4               # advance to next array element
    subi    $t1,$t1,1               # decrement count
    bgtz    $t1,init_loop           # more to do? if yes, loop

    jr      $ra                     # return

# print_array -- initialize array with random values
#
# arguments:
#   a0 -- array address
#   a1 -- array count
#
# registers:
#   t0 -- array address
#   t1 -- array index
print_array:
    move    $t0,$a0                 # prevent value from being clobbered
    li      $t1,0                   # array index

print_array_loop:
    move    $a0,$t1                 # index value
    li      $v0,1                   # syscall for print int
    syscall

    la      $a0,separator
    li      $v0,4
    syscall

    lw      $a0,0($t0)              # get array value
    li      $v0,1                   # syscall for print int
    syscall

    # output a newline
    la      $a0,nl
    li      $v0,4
    syscall

    addiu   $t0,$t0,4               # advance to next array element
    addi    $t1,$t1,1               # increment index
    blt     $t1,$a1,print_array_loop    # more to do? if yes, loop

    jr      $ra                     # return
```

---

Here is the fixed and running version. I added the missing `init_array` and `print_array` functions as well as the results printing. The boilerplate code you were given also had some [minor] bugs that I fixed. I tried to remain faithful to your `find_max` code, but, unfortunately, I needed to refactor it.

Also, make note of the fact that under the mips ABI, the `$v*`, `$a*`, and `$t*` can be used by the called function for *any* purpose. So, modifying the `$s*` registers was never an issue internally for `find_max`.

```
    .data                           # data segment
    .align  2                       # important for words
###buffer:      .space      4096        # allocate space for 1K words
buffer:     .space      128     # allocate space for 1K words
bufe:

nl:         .asciiz     "\n"        # ASCII for a new line
separator:  .asciiz     ":"         # string that seprates index from number

msg1:       .asciiz     "The function returned "

msg2:       .asciiz     "\nThe maximum value is "
msg3:       .asciiz     "\nThe address of the word is "

    .text                           # Code segment
    .globl  main                    # declare main to be global

main:
    addiu   $sp,$sp,-4              # allocate space on the stack for $s0
    sw      $s0,($sp)               # save $s0

    # specify the size of the array, must be less than 1024
    la      $s0,bufe                # get address of array end
    la      $a0,buffer              # get address of array
    subu    $s0,$s0,$a0             # get byte length of array
    srl     $s0,$s0,2               # get word count of array

    la      $a0,buffer
    move    $a1,$s0
    jal     init_array              # initialize the array with random values

    la      $a0,buffer
    move    $a1,$s0
    jal     print_array             # call print. You can comment it out.

    # call your find_max function
    la      $a0,buffer
    move    $a1,$s0
    jal     find_max                # call find_max
    move    $t0,$v0                 # save address
    move    $t1,$v1                 # save value

    # add code to print the results

    # print the maximum value
    la      $a0,msg2                # print mssage 2
    li      $v0,4
    syscall
    move    $a0,$t1                 # get max value
    li      $v0,1
    syscall
    la      $a0,nl
    li      $v0,4
    syscall

    # print the address of the value (in hex).
    la      $a0,msg3                # print mssage 3
    li      $v0,4
    syscall
    move    $a0,$t0                 # get address of max value
    li      $v0,34
    syscall
    la      $a0,nl
    li      $v0,4
    syscall

    # restore  $s0. You can check $sp here to make sure the stack is maintained     correctly.
    lw      $s0,($sp)               # load $s0
    addiu   $sp,$sp,4               # restore $sp

    li      $v0,10                  # exit program
    syscall                         # ...and call the OS

# your implementation of find_max
#
# RETURNS:
#   v0 -- address of maximum value
#   v1 -- maximum value
#
# arguments:
#   a0 -- buffer address
#   a1 -- buffer count
#
# registers:
#   t0 -- current value
#   t1 -- test/temporary
find_max:
    addiu   $sp,$sp,-16             # allocate stack space for four registers
    sw      $s0,($sp)               # save $s0
    sw      $s1,4($sp)              # save $s1
    sw      $s2,8($sp)              # save $s2
    sw      $s3,12($sp)             # save $s3

    # put your code below.
    # You can use temporary registers and $s0 to $s3

    # initialize the maximum value from the first element
    move    $v0,$a0                 # get the address
    lw      $v1,0($a0)              # get the value

find_max_loop:
    addiu   $a0,$a0,4               # advance buffer pointer
    subi    $a1,$a1,1               # decrement remaining count
    blez    $a1,find_max_done       # more to do? if no, return

    lw      $t0,0($a0)              # get current value
    slt     $t1,$v1,$t0             # got new maximum?
    beqz    $t1,find_max_loop       # no, loop

    move    $v0,$a0                 # set new maximum pointer
    move    $v1,$t0                 # set new maximum value
    j       find_max_loop           # try next value

    # restore saved registers.
    # make sure $sp is restored if you changed it.
find_max_done:
    lw      $s0,($sp)
    lw      $s1,4($sp)
    lw      $s2,8($sp)
    lw      $s3,12($sp)
    addiu   $sp,$sp,16              # restore $sp
    jr      $ra                     # return to calling routine

# init_array -- initialize array with random values
#
# arguments:
#   a0 -- array address
#   a1 -- array count
#
# registers:
#   t0 -- array address
#   t1 -- array count
init_array:
    move    $t0,$a0                 # prevent value from being clobbered
    move    $t1,$a1                 # prevent value from being clobbered

    # seed the generator
    li      $v0,40
    li      $a0,0
    li      $a1,0x12345678
    syscall

init_loop:
    li      $v0,41                  # syscall for random int
    li      $a0,0                   # specify which generator to use
    syscall

    sw      $a0,0($t0)              # store into array
    addiu   $t0,$t0,4               # advance to next array element
    subi    $t1,$t1,1               # decrement count
    bgtz    $t1,init_loop           # more to do? if yes, loop

    jr      $ra                     # return

# print_array -- initialize array with random values
#
# arguments:
#   a0 -- array address
#   a1 -- array count
#
# registers:
#   t0 -- array address
#   t1 -- array index
print_array:
    move    $t0,$a0                 # prevent value from being clobbered
    li      $t1,0                   # array index

print_array_loop:
    move    $a0,$t1                 # index value
    li      $v0,1                   # syscall for print int
    syscall

    la      $a0,separator
    li      $v0,4
    syscall

    lw      $a0,0($t0)              # get array value
    li      $v0,1                   # syscall for print int
    syscall

    # output a newline
    la      $a0,nl
    li      $v0,4
    syscall

    addiu   $t0,$t0,4               # advance to next array element
    addi    $t1,$t1,1               # increment index
    blt     $t1,$a1,print_array_loop    # more to do? if yes, loop

    jr      $ra                     # return
```