# Array elements in MIPS

Tags: arrays, mips, element

How do I take the elements out of an array?
I.e.

```
 array: 1, 2, 3, 4
 sw a0, array
```

How do I write in code that I want to use the elements from a0?

Comment: I think you'll need explain in more detail what you mean by "take the elements out of an array". If you just want an example of how to loop through an array and use them in some way, then see my recent answer here for a few different ways to manipulate an array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39628049/mars-mips-out-of-range-error/39630621#39630621

Comment: Note that `sw a0, array` is incorrect if what you wanted to do was load the address of `array` into register `a0`.